# How to insert a space as a first character inside of backticks in comments?

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I tried to insert `b>` in comments, but I could not do this, it rendered as a standard text with backticks. Why? How to insert this code:

```
`   text`
```

in comments so it renders as `text` with three visible spaces?

Comment: Test: ` text` and ` text` and ` text` and ` text`

Comment: Test comment markup:  `\` text\``, ` text`

Comment: @aroth: how to render this as a code without backticks?

Comment: Don't know, haven't stumbled upon a functional way to do that yet.  Even Unicode whitespace characters seem to throw it off.

Comment: So, it is impossible to render at least one visible space at the beginning and no spaces at the end?

Comment: Precede with ZWSP, then NBSP for multiple spaces `​    text`

Comment: Btw, I covered it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175364/single-code-formatted-space-works-in-questions-and-answers-but-not-comments/175367#175367 which is closed as dup of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug

Comment: @nhahtdh: Thank you. Yes, duplicate! But strange, those answers were not shown by search when I tried to find a solution. Currently, they are not even shown here on this page, at the right side...

Comment: @lyricallywicked: It's on Meta.SE (The Great Meta), not Meta.SO (here).

Comment: @nhahtdh: Ah, yes. Anyway, I did not managed to find them using search engines (incl. Google) by keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [solution/workaround](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/my-comment-code-block-was-not-converted-properly-is-this-a-bug) was pointed out in the comments (use a unicode char).

However, this question also asked "why?"

It is all explained in the official?/original [Markdown Syntax Rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:
>
> ```
> A single backtick in a code span: `` ` ``
>
> A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` ``
> ```
>
> will produce:
>
> ```
> <p>A single backtick in a code span: <code>`</code></p>
>
> <p>A backtick-delimited string in a code span: <code>`foo`</code></p>
> ```

To enforce that rule, Markdown parsers generally will strip any white-space at the beginning and end of the code span. As the rules specifically state "one after the opening, one before the closing" it could be argued that only one space should be removed rather than all of them. However, it can be difficult for a document author to tell the difference between one and two spaces, so the parser (correctly IMO) assumes that the extra spaces were a typo and removes them all. This was the behavior implemented in the original reference implementation (markdown.pl), and all (most?) other implementations have copied that behavior.