# Code block delimited with <pre> and scroll bars

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

I just saw this

```
    Lorem ipsum
```

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id vestibulum justo. Aenean ac diam id nisl bibendum porta.
```

Renders on my chrome (73.0.3683.86) as [image: Code block]

I'm (having zero familiarity with HTML) assuming the floating scroll bar and only applying to half of the code block are bugs?

Comment: renders the same on my firefox, fwiw

Comment: Same on up-to-date chrome

Comment: Same on latest Safari.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382183/can-we-do-something-about-posters-using-pre-html-tags-in-code-blocks

Comment: FWIW, the HTML generated by the SE Markdown parser is `<p><pre>
    Lorem ipsum</p>

<pre><code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id vestibulum justo. Aenean ac diam id nisl bibendum porta.
</code></pre>

<p></pre></p>`. That's pretty broken by any standards.

Comment: That generated html looks almost as broken as the html generated by Confluence.

Comment: @luk2302 I've just started using Confluence for work reasons, and that truth burns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior that results from indenting the start of a HTML block is undefined. From [the documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#html):

> Block-level HTML elements have a few restrictions:
>
> 1. They must be separated from surrounding text by blank lines.
> 2. The begin and end tags of the outermost block element **must not be indented.**
> 3. Markdown can't be used within HTML blocks.

(emphasis mine)

The actual behavior in this case is... Weird: the `<pre>` block is still allowed and passed through to the result, but the contents of the block are also parsed as Markdown and rendered accordingly - so you get another `<pre>` block and some paragraphs nested in the outer block.

This behavior was previously noted on MSE: [Code block markdown formatting using <pre>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278731/code-block-markdown-formatting-using-pre)

I'm leaving this marked as a bug because the behavior is inconsistent both with what the documentation *implies* and with what we should expect future versions of the rendering engine to support - in other words, this behavior is generally undesirable and should not be relied on *even when it is desirable*.

Answer (score 15):

Yeah it is a bug.

The reason is the leading whitespace of the `<pre>`:

```
 <pre>
^
```

Also interesting, backticks (with leading whitespace) have problems too:

```
`test`, `<pre>`, ` test`, ` <pre>`
```

Renders in comments (totally wrong):

[image: Rendered Picture]

Renders in answer block (white space is missing):

`test`, `<pre>`, `test`, `<pre>`

Comment: `test`, `<pre>`, ` test`, ` <pre>`

Comment: You mean the markup is interpreted differently in a post and in a comment? I saw multiple bug report for that in the past: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274276/backticks-within-backticks-work-differently-in-posts-and-in-comments

Comment: It would be *by design* that spaces break markup:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297113/how-to-insert-a-space-as-a-first-character-inside-of-backticks-in-comments